# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch while updating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to uodate a model by posting a form to the update method. The scenario is that we have clubs and each club belongs to a region.

The model is:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :club
end

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :region
end
```

My view uses to create the form select element:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:region, Region.all, :id, :caption, {}, {class: "form-control"} ) %>
```

And my controller looks like this

```
def update
    @club = Club.find(params[:id])
    if @club.update(club_params)
        redirect_to @club
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

THe param region is permitted. Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `region_id` instead of `region` (also in `club_params` implementation):

```
<%= f.collection_select(:region_id, Region.all, :id, :caption, {}, {class: "form-control"} ) %>
```

From your comment I guess you should also generate migration adding `region_id` column to your `clubs` table:

```
bundle exec rails g migration add_region_id_to_clubs region:references
```

and run it:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I've tried that already. The I get the error: NoMethodError in Clubs#edit (undefined method `region_id' for #<Club:0x000000055b4bb8>) when I open the edit-form

Comment: @Gerrit did you add `region_id` column to your `clubs` table?

Comment: This is my migration change_table :clubs do |t|
    t.references :regions
   end

Comment: @Gerrit it should be `t.references :region`. So run `bundle exec rake db:rollback`, then edit your migration and run it again.